# Long SQL Queries - INSERT, UPDATE

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2014

O.,

For some reason today, the usual queries i'd make are taking exponentially longer, for example a similar set size may take 0:05 - 0:10 to process whereas the same style queries are taking as long as 15 - 45 minutes today.

I create new output tables for the data, is it possible I have miscreated the table and this would dramatically increase process time? I looked at the activity log but nothing look like a big red flag there...

```
UPDATE [WORKING_TABLE]
SET postcode = b.[postcode], first_name = b.[first_name], ll_id = b.[id]
FROM [OTHER_DB].[dbo].[SOURCE_TABLE] b, [WORKING_TABLE] o
WHERE UPPER(o.email) = UPPER(b.email)
```

I know this isn't the best way to approach it, but with the (usually) small wait time I wasn't overly concerned.

When I ran into the issue I tried a setup like this, which I found when googling the issue

```
UPDATE [WORKING_TABLE]
  SET [postcode] = b.[postcode], first_name = b.[first_name], ll_id = b.[id]
  FROM [WORKING_TABLE] AS t1
  INNER JOIN [OTHER_DB].[dbo].[SOURCE_TABLE] AS b
  ON UPPER(t1.email) = UPPER(b.email)
  WHERE b.postcode is not null AND b.first_name is not null
OPTION (LOOP JOIN, QUERYTRACEON 8649);
```

Anything pop into mind that can cause this?

Comment: The biggest pop into my mind is when you recreated the tables have you considered recreating the indexes?. Also, if you have an index on email then don't use the UPPER function in the joining condition. Rather, update your tables to UPPER and then use the join without the upper.

Comment: @Ala thanks for quick reply, I'm doing a test now without the UPPER in the loop.

When I recreated the table I just made an empty table and inserted the relevant record segments - This would mean the indexes are already reset?

Comment: Nope. Browse your old database, go these tables, and see the created indexes. Script them and run them against your new tables then try running your update query.

Comment: And please let the optimizer do its work to give you the best results if you are not 100% sure of what you are doing when you force it to use a LOOP JOIN.

Comment: @Ala,  I usually dont force any settings, just in this specific case it made sense to try the parrallel threads - In my testing since your advice I have been leaving this out. 

As an update I think my SOURCE_TABLE may be the cause of the issue, as I quickly selected the sections I needed from this table and made a new SOURCE2 table - at which point my queries are returning to normal speed.